# jQuery change event not firing from keyboard?

Tags: events, dom, jquery-selectors, jquery

I have this `dropdown`, I want to alert/log something when the value in it is changed. What happens is when I click the `dropdown` with mouse, and selected any other value, the change event is fired. But when the focus is in the `dropdown`, and I press `up` and `down` arrow, it changes the value in dropdown, but the event is not fired, and the alert is now showing up.
Here's the code

```
<select id="drpDay" name="drpDay" style="background-color: white;">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7" selected="selected">7</option>    
    </select>
</br>
<select id="drpMonth" name="drpMonth" style="background-color: white;">
        <option value="Jan">Jan</option>
        <option value="Feb">Feb</option>
        <option value="Mar">Mar</option>
        <option value="Apr">Apr</option>
        <option value="May">May</option>
        <option value="Jun">Jun</option>
        <option value="Jul">Jul</option>
        <option value="Aug">Aug</option>
        <option value="Sep">Sep</option>
        <option value="Oct">Oct</option>
        <option value="Nov" selected="selected">Nov</option>
        <option value="Dec">Dec</option>    
    </select>
</br>
<label id="lbl" text="" width="auto">adsf</label>
```

The js is

```
$('#drpDay, #drpMonth').change(function(event) {
    alert(event.which);
    $('#lbl').text('change ' + event.which + ' and ' + $(event.target).attr('id'));
});
```

Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2NBPx/4/

What I want is when the value in select box changes, event by pressing `up` and/or `down` arrow, I want that event to be fired. Why is not firing, and how do I make it fire on change from keyboard?

Comment: Do you mean when the list is down and you can press up and down to highlight the item you want to select. If so, at that point the value hasn't changed, only when you select an item with a mouse click or pressing enter the the value changes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bind it to keyup and change like so: http://jsfiddle.net/2NBPx/6/

```
$('#drpDate, #drpMonth').on('change keyup',function(event) {
    if($(this).data('last') !== $(this).val()){
        $(this).data('last', $(this).val());            
        $('#lbl').text('For change ' + event.which + ' and you ' + $(event.target).attr('id'));
    }
});
```

UPDATE: is only fired when an actual change happens.

Answer (score 2):

The following will ensure that the change event fires **whenever the selection changes**, via the keyboard or the mouse.

```
var prevValue = null;

$('#drpDay').change(function() {
    console.log('changed');
    prevValue = this.value;
});

$('#drpDay').keyup(function() {
    if(prevValue != this.value) {
        $(this).trigger('change');
    }
});
```

Check this **demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/ZCxe8/

Answer (score 1):

What browser are you using ?

In my Chrome and IE9, the fiddle that you provided works fine with the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You could combine the `change` and `keyup` event. If your event handler should only do his work when the value has actually changed then you will have to add some more logic into it (remember the old value, compare, act, ...)

```
$('#drpDay, #drpMonth').on("change keyup", function(event) {
    //...
});
```

Comment: For jQuery's `on` events are space separated not with commas. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: But won't this fire even when nothing changes? i.e. when user presses esc or space while the focus is on the `<select>`?